# C++ Class functions return values VS operate on local data?

Tags: c++, class, oop, design-patterns, system-design

Suppose that we have class C and our process is as follows

1. do func1
2. do func2
3. do func3
4. do func4

where each function operates on the data from the previous stage

Which is better from the point of view of system design?

1. make each func takes an input, returns its results and pass the result to the next stage
2. make each func operate on data members in the class c and they all return void

And if these 2 strategies are famous design patters what is the name of each design pattern?

Comment: You forgot a third alternative: Have `func1` call `func2`, which calls `func3` etc. Of course, this can be mixed with the to alternatives you have as well, so it's really two more alternatives.

Comment: you should not make class and use variables data members until most of the functions use those data members. if your requirement simulates a chain i-e fun4 depends on fun 3 ,fun3 depends on func 2 and so on then use following model fun4(return value from fun 3(return value from fun2)) and so on

Comment: I hate it when I see option 2 used casually. It does occaisionally have it's uses, but then class C's only purpose should be to execute this processing.

Comment: Thanks all but is there a specific professional name for these strategies ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use option 2, and you'll pass the code to another developer. If he/she accidentally calls func3(), func4() in the middle of the code, it will be logically wrong.

If you use option 1, the developer needs to think of the parameters which will be passed through. It is less likely that he will make mistake.

Therefore, I'll go with option 1.